# Typing problems in Tinn-R

Tags: r, character, tinn-r

I use Tinn-R 3.0.3.6 with Windows 7 and I cannot type # and ] characters in the editor of Tinn-R. When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Gr</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> (should be <kbd>#</kbd>), nothing happens. When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Gr</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd> (should be <kbd>]</kbd>), the numbering of the lines disappear, so it seems to work as a shortcut for this option. Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Key bindings will depend on the localization of your system. On my keyboard, `#` is SHIFT+3, for example. Tinn-R may be taking over some of the bindings. I suggest you switch to a different GUI. I recommend, RStudio, Eclipse + StatET or ESS.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved in `TinnR Options / Shortcuts` and resetting all shortcuts conflicting with `alt gr + x` and `alt gr + g` (be sure to reset `ctrl + alt + g/x` and `shift + alt + g/x` - that's when I succeeded...)